# What is the best way to make an RDF Model accessible in a JSP view?

Tags: java, spring, rdf, jena, sesame

I am writing an Java web application that fetches RDF data from URIs and stores them in a Jena Model object. Currently the models contain ordinary triples, some Blank Nodes, no inference. (That is described here already [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252458/use-apache-jena-to-get-rdf-from-url)). Using Sesame would be an option, too.

After data collection, the application displays some of the collected information in a specified order. It would be necessary to build filters on the model using predicates only and filters specifiying subject & predicate (as we will collect data from several sources); in each case, the object-literal or URI would be displayed.

**What would be the best way to generically access the model's contents from a JSP-View (without writing custom tags for each function)?**

The **JSP-View** would look like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="${modelBean.model.depictionPred}"/>
        Name: <c:out value="${modelBean.model.namePred}"/><br/>
        Life dates: <c:out value="${modelBean.model.birthPred}"/>-<c:out value="${modelBean.model.deathPred}"/><br/>
        Links: <a href="${modelBean.model.linkPred}">Linktext</a><br/>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

**Jena-Servlet** to collect data:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            ModelBean modelBean = new ModelBean();
            Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
            model.read("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ludwig_van_Beethoven");
            modelBean.setModel(model);
            request.setAttribute("modelBean", modelBean);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
```

**Sesame-Variant of the Servlet:**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ModelBean modelBean = new ModelBean();

        URL url = new URL("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ludwig_van_Beethoven");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", RDFFormat.TURTLE.getDefaultMIMEType());
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        try {
           Model model = Rio.parse(is, url.toString(), RDFFormat.forMIMEType(conn.getContentType()));
        } catch (RDFParseException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(ModelViewTester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        finally {
           is.close(); 
        }
        modelBean.setModel(model);
        request.setAttribute("modelBean", modelBean);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Well, as a `Model` in Sesame is simply a Java Collection, you could iterate over it from JSP like any other `Set`, `List`, or `Map`. You will need to provide a bit more detail for this question to be answerable though. A code example that illustrates what you're trying to achieve would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I now added a code example implementing this. Now the question would be how to actually access the Literals in the Graph (My example simply prints the contents via toString()). E.g. How could I access the name of Beethoven via <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> in the JSP?

Comment: Now I've added a Sesame example, too.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're getting at. Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121303/how-to-call-parameterized-method-from-jsp-using-jstl ?

Comment: Thanks, Jeen; yes, passing parameters to bean methods is exactly what I was missing. If you put this into an answer; I'll accept it. Thanks also for the edit - my old Sesame code felt a bit lengthy to me, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that something may be possible by providing parameters to calls on bean methods (see [How to call parameterized method from JSP using JSTL/EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121303/how-to-call-parameterized-method-from-jsp-using-jstl) ) I'm afraid you'll have to either create custom tags, or you need to rethink your access strategy.

For example, rather than putting the entire RDF `Model` into your response, you could do the extraction of relevant data at the servlet-side, and just put the relevant properties that you want to display in your view response, as separate bean properties.